# Filter a NumPy array by the final dimension, collapsing only the second to last dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I am so incredibly confused battling this problem, even though it's super simple:

I have a numpy array `a` where `a.shape == (16,4,1000,60)`

I really dislike it when `a[:,:,:,5] == x`

I want to remove all of the above, to produce `b` where `b.shape == (16,4,k,60)`, where `k` is an unknown but constant number.

The indexes where `a[0,0,:,5] == x` are not necessarily the same as the indexes where `a[0,1,:,5] == x`, but there are always `k` of them.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT:
I've just discovered that if I do:

```
b = a[a[:,:,:,5] == x]
k = b.size / (16*4*60)
b = b.reshape([16,4,k,60])
b.shape # e.g. (16,4,3,60)
```

It works, but this doesn't seem like a very nice solution. Is there a way to explicitly keep dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `b = b.reshape([16,4,k,60])` just do a `b = b.reshape((16,4,-1,60))`.  `numpy` will figure out the implicit dimension for you.

One and *only one* shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the total size of the array and the other dimensions.